# how to display information underneath a specific button using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code I am working on. My purpose is to be able to grab information about different users from a specific website, display the name and other info and then have a button that when clicked, prints more information. I am able to get the information and display the name and picture, but when I click the button the information is displayed at the top of the page, not under the specific button that was clicked. I want for the information to be display under each user... I am new to Javascript and learning on my own, any help is appreciated!

```
function getUsers(user) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
        out += '<a href="' + user[i].url + '">' + user[i].login + '</a><br>'+'</br> <img src="'+user[i].avatar_url+
               '" alt="Image" style="width:304px;height:228px"</br></br>'+
               '<button onclick=printRepos("'+user[i].repos_url+'")>Repositories</button></br>'+'<div id="id"></div>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Printing Function

```
function printF(array) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        out += array[i].id+'</br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: A closing `</br>` tag doesn't exist. Maybe you mean `<br />`?

Comment: It's because you're creating a bunch of divs with the same id (id="id") and later when you try to write to that div your browser picks the first one it finds.

Comment: Yeah, syntax mistake there. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: I understand the part with the same ids, my question is how to create different id's and be able to pass them to the printing function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine. I just made div with dynamic ids and passed it to the function

```
function getUsers(user) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
         out += '<a href="' + user[i].url + '">' + user[i].login + '</a>   <br>'+'</br> <img src="'+user[i].avatar_url+
           '" alt="Image" style="width:304px;height:228px"</br></br>'+
           '<button onclick=printRepos("'+user[i].repos_url+'","'+i+'")>Repositories</button></br>'+'<div id="'+ 'id' + i +'"></div>';
    }

   document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}


function printRepos(array, id) {

    var out = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        out += array[i].id+'</br>';
    }

    console.log('id' + id);

    document.getElementById('id' + id).innerHTML = out;


}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. I will give it a try

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help! I passed the id of the user through the function and used that to id each div.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "this" keyword as a parameter to your onclicks, to pass in the button that was clicked:

```
<button onclick=printRepos(this,"'+user[i].repos_url+'")>Repositories</button>
```

Then locate the next div after that button in your event handler:

```
function printF(btn, array) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        out += array[i].id+'</br>';
    }
    // find the div
    var d = btn;  // start with the button
    while (d.tagName != "DIV") d = d.nextSibling; // look for the next div
    d.innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post! I'll have it as an alternative idea for the future. Appreciate it